# Flex and php newbie question

Tags: php, apache-flex

I have read on the adobe website that you could use php with flex.I know for applications to run on the desktop they have to be a .air format,like most tweeter desktop clients.I am therefore curious,wont one need things like apache and mysql for your app in php and flex or is everything transformed into a single .air including all your webserver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP is used for the backend only. The client is written in Flex. Both communicate via [AMF](http://corlan.org/2009/03/31/flex-and-remoting-with-php-which-library-is-the-best-zend-amf-amfphp-weborb-for-php-or-sabreamf/). So yes, you need a webserver and network connection for this. See [The architecture of Flex and PHP applications](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/flex_php_architecture.html)

Answer (score 0):

The .air file contacts your webserver over their internet connection.